# Making false the readonly of a Div

Tags: asp.net

I am using a multiline textbox for publishing a note but taking the content in a div through inner HTMl.
like this

divMessageDescription.InnerHtml = dbreader["Message"].ToString();

but now for a particular group of people I want to make the read only property of this div as false..

Can I do this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use div for text editing, you can use multi-line text box (textarea). Even for display purpose, you may use the same textbox with read-only set as true.

Answer (score 1):

To make the div editable (read only = false) you use the **contentEditable="true"**

```
<div id="divMessageDescription" contentEditable="true">
             click here to edit ...</div>
```